# Facebook Messenger Platform Send Local Image Attachment

Tags: facebook, bots, facebook-messenger

I'm trying to send an image locally via the Send API, but am not having any luck using the following structure:

dataUrl in this context is a base64 encoded data URL generated via Canvas.

```
const body = JSON.stringify({
   recipient: { id },
   message: {
      attachment: {
         type: 'image',
         payload: {}
      }
   },
   filedata: dataUrl
});
```

Comment: Hi, did you get to resolve this issue? I am having the same problem right now and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways of sending an attachment on facebook messenger(Send) API, as per the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages#sending_attachments). 
There seems to be no support for sending attachments as Base64 encoded data, the closest thing you can to get this done is to convert the base64 encoded data to a file on your server and then upload it from your server using the (Attachment from file) option as provided by facebook.

### Sending Attachments

> The Messenger Platform allows you to attach assets to messages, including audio, video, images, and files. The maximum attachment size is 25 MB. The maximum resolution for images is 85 Megapixel. There are three ways to attach an asset to a message:
>
> 1. URL
> 2. File
> 3. attachment_id

### Attachment types

> Attachment Types
> The Messenger Platform supports the following attachment types, specified in the attachment.type property of the message:
>
> 1. audio
> 2. video
> 3. image
> 4. file
> 5. template. For more info on this type, see Templates

#### 1. Attaching from URL

> To send an attachment from a URL, submit a POST request to the Send API, with message.attachment set in the request body. The attachment object includes the asset type (image, audio, video, or file), and a payload that includes the asset url:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "recipient":{
    "id":"1254459154682919"
  },
  "message":{
    "attachment":{
      "type":"image", 
      "payload":{
        "url":"http://www.messenger-rocks.com/image.jpg", 
        "is_reusable":true
      }
    }
  }
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/me/messages?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

#### 2. Attaching from File

> To send an attachment from file, submit a POST request to the Send API with the message details as form data, with the following fields:
> recipient: A JSON object identifying the message recipient.
> message: A JSON object describing the message. Includes the asset type, and a payload. The payload is either empty, or sets the is_reusable property.
> filedata:The location of the asset on your file system and MIME type.

```
curl  \
  -F 'recipient={"id":"<PSID>"}' \
  -F 'message={"attachment":{"type":"<ASSET_TYPE>", "payload":{"is_reusable":true}}}' \
  -F 'filedata=@/tmp/shirt.png;type=image/png' \
  "https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/me/messages?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

#### 3. Attaching Saved Assets

> The Messenger Platform supports saving assets via the Send API and Attachment Upload API. This allows you reuse assets, rather than uploading them every time they are needed. For information on saving assets, see Saving Assets.
> To attach a saved asset to a message, specify the attachment_id of the asset in the payload.attachment_id property of the message request:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "recipient":{
    "id":"1254459154682919"
  },
  "message":{
    "attachment":{
      "type":"image", 
      "payload":{
        "attachment_id": "1745504518999123"
      }
    }
  }
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/me/messages?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```